# Kerberos authentication with Node.js

Tags: security, node.js, kerberos

I need to access a service (RESTful) which supports only Kerberos authentication from my Node.js application. Is there any module in Node to do this?

[Passport](http://passportjs.org/), the popular authentication module for Node.js, doesn't seem to have a strategy for Kerberos auth.

Comment: [node-krb5](https://github.com/qesuto/node-krb5)?

Comment: It doesn't look like a mature one. Have you used it?

Comment: nope but it is node you probably won't find many "mature" modules.

Comment: [node-libvirt](https://github.com/c4milo/node-libvirt) also can remote auth using krb if you wanted to look at their source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not many kerberos modules in the npm registry, but this one seems a more reasonable choice currently:

https://npmjs.org/package/kerberos

I would use it with passport and a local strategy as default.

Comment: For anyone seeing this in the future, the kerberos package is mongodb specific, and is left undocumented as "it's not generally usable."
https://twitter.com/christkv/status/580338769330589696

Comment: @Salem I have used kerberos module successfully in many non mongodb environments with great success.  It can (now) be used as client or server side kerberos support library, as demonstrated by the [passport-negotiate](https://github.com/dmansfield/passport-negotiate) module which provides server side authentication using Negotiate/spnego

Answer (score 0):

I use local strategy as default strategy. and use node-krb5 to verify the username and passwd. it's work, you can have a try.